# Change Size of DataGrid Row Selection Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want the selection button bigger. I have this:

```
<DataGrid Name="testGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ColumnWidth="100"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                      CanUserSortColumns="False"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      SelectionMode="Extended">
```

But it stays small:

[image]

Comment: iam not sure but maybe its because u set the size already here `ColumnWidth="100"`

Comment: The ColumnWidth has nothing to do with it, and indeed SelectionMode is for selection. But is there a way to make it bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `RowHeaderWidth` property:

```
<DataGrid Name="testGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ColumnWidth="100"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"

                  RowHeaderWidth="50"

                  >
```